# How to access Neptune DB (Gremlin) in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Is there anyway to access neptune DB(Gremlin) using lambda functions?

I want to access neptune DB(gremlin) and I don't know how to access.

Comment: Add more info on what you environment is.

Comment: I used AWS for the first time and I created Neptune DB instance and EC2 instance.
I tested using neptune DB can access Gremlin console and i want to know, can access neptune using lambda?

Comment: Looks like you'd need to build a package that includes `gremlin`: [Using Node.js to Connect to a Neptune DB Instance - Amazon Neptune](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-node-js.html)

Comment: For those who are still looking for a code sample to connect Lambda to AWS Neptune: https://github.com/hardikvasa/database-journal/blob/master/code-samples/aws_neptune.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can access Amazon Neptune from Lambda. Let's say, as an example, you wanted to use Python, as part of the ZIP file that you upload to Lambda you would need to include the Gremlin Python libraries in the ZIP file. The Lambda documentation has some good examples of how to create that ZIP file. You also need to make sure that the Lambda function has access to the VPC that Neptune is running in.

Comment: when I test my gremlin function(index.js), show this error message:

Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'"
}

Please let me know what am I missing

Comment: Your Lambda function needs to provide a handler method that Lambda can call. Have you seen the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html ? Hopefully that will help.